# How to prove that a given group is isomorphic to Sym(4)?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Given a specific group with 24 elements, I want to prove that it is isomorphic to Sym(4).

To begin with, I calculate the orders of my group's elements and they come out as in the order statistics for Sym(4):
1 of order 1, 9 of order 2, 8 of order 3 and 6 of order 4.
Now as I understand, matching the elements orders is not enough to show isomorphism for non-abelian groups.
But I was wondering if in this particular case it happens to be enough, since there are only 15 groups of order 24.
See the [groupprops database](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_groups_of_order_24).
Unfortunately, this database does not list the order statistics for all the other groups of order 24 so I can rule them out.
Is there any other place where I can find their order statistics?

If the above method does not work, then I'm thinking to show isomorphism as follows: my group is a set of
24 elements and it also acts on various sets of elements.
I can take a specific set with 4 elements and show by direct calculations that my group acts on it
by permuting these 4 elements.
I do indeed get all the 24 permutations. Would this be enough to prove isomorphism to Sym(4)?
If so, what well-known theorem can I quote in support? (I only know the very basics of group theory.)

Comment: Two points: Unless the group order is small (and to be fair 24 is a very small so it 'might' work but not sure) calculating order of element and comparing is not the best idea, especially for a first learner. So i suggest you do not use this method.

My second point is that I have no idea how your group is given as. Proving two group being isomorphic normally does not have systematic method so it would help if you post how you know the group as. From my guess you have group table given?

Comment: And your second method would work but you obviously will have to prove it satisfies group action law which might be annoying if you are given a multiplication table or something like that.

Comment: The group elements are formulas, and they also act on sets of formulas.
It is really too tedious to describe here.
But if the group action law you mention means compatibility between the external and internal operations,
then yes, I was able to prove that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact in this case the order statistics do give you enough information to prove that the group is isomorphic to $S_4$ but I agree with Jack Yoon that this may not be the best approach.

A group of order $24$ has $1$ or $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups, and the fact that there are $8$ elements of order $3$ shows that there must be $4$.

The image $P$ of the conjugation action of $G$ on the set of its Sylow $3$-subgroups is transitive, with a Sylow $3$-subgroup fixing a unique point, so $P$ contains $A_4$.

If $P = A_4$ then $G$ would have a normal and hence unique Sylow $2$-subgroup, in which case there would be just $7$ elements of order $2$ or $4$, which is not the case. Hence $P=S_4$ and $P \cong G$.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the first part, I was just about to *suggest* the method of your last paragraph. This is the preferred method to show the desired result, I suppose. For example, the symmetry group of a cube has $24$ elements because we can pick a face and for this face four different orientations. The fact that the group is isomorphic to $S_4$ becomes immediately apparent when one notices that the group acts faithfully(!) on the four-element set of spacial diagonals.